# How does a linker decide which specific version of a shared library should be linked to?

Tags: python, linux, ld

On Rocky Linux 8, the default Python 3 links against `libcrypto.so.1.1`. But when I compile (a newer) Python from source, it links against `libcrypto.so.1` instead. Can anyone explain where this difference comes from?

Some more details how this can be reproduced (everything can be run in a fresh Rocky Linux 8 Docker container):

1. Install Python 3 on Rocky 8:

   ```bash
   dnf install -y python3
   ```
2. Check the dependencies of libpython:

   ```bash
   ldd /usr/lib64/libpython3.so
   ```

   which gives

   ```
   libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f1d53c2c000)
   ```
3. Get a Python tarball and compile it from source:

   ```bash
   dnf groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
   dnf install -y \
     bzip2-devel \
     libffi-devel \
     openssl-devel \
     zlib-devel
   curl -fLO 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.8/Python-3.10.8.tgz'
   tar -xvf Python-3.10.8.tgz
   cd Python-3.10.8
   ./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations --with-lto
   make -j 4
   make install
   cd ..
   ```
4. Check the dependencies of libpython:

   ```bash
   ldd /usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.so
   ```

   which gives

   ```
   libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f96325ef000)
   ```

Some more background:

I try to create a self-contained executable of a Python program with [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/). PyInstaller detects that `libcrypt.so.1.1` is needed and includes it in the distribution. However, `libpython3.10.so` expects `libcrypt.so.1` instead and fails to load.

Comment: The linker decides nothing, it links exactly what you tell it to link. If PyInstaller detects that libcrypt.so.1.1 is needed when actually libcrypt.so.1 is needed, then it's probably a PyInstaller problem. BTW libcrypt and libcrypto are two very different libraries.

Comment: Ah... thanks, I did not see that one is `libcrypt` and the other one is `libcrypto`. :(